# Transition between two single-page-app pages within the same angular application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

How could I move from a page that uses an `ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd"` and its own set of CSS and JavaScript to a different page that uses `ng-app="MyAppAdminEnd"` and has its own set of CSS and JavaScript?

I am using ExpressJS and NodeJS at the server end for routing.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'My App Front End Title' });
});

/* GET admin front */
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'My App Admin End Title' });
});
```

`index.ejs` uses `ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd"` and `users.ejs` uses `ng-app="MyAppAdminEnd"`.

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: Do you mean without a page reload?

Comment: @user2847643: No, the `users.ejs` is going to be loaded when `/users` is called. But I want to call `/users` from the `index.ejs` that uses `ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd"` to `users.ejs` that uses `ng-app="MyAppAdminEnd"`.

Comment: I am tired so I might not be thinking straight but if you can just reload the page then what is the problem?

Comment: @user2847643: I want to call `/users` from the `index.ejs` that uses `ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd"` to `users.ejs` that uses `ng-app="MyAppAdminEnd"`. Would calling `href="/users"` not try to find that route within `ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd"` if I tried it from `index.ejs`?

Comment: So a link like `<a href="/users">link</a>` does not work? That should skip all the angular stuff and just go straight for the server. I think I am missing something here.

Comment: I get that. Those are different apps on the same server and you are worried that a reference to /users from frontend will be magically handled by angular and not reload the page. But I don't think that is the case at least if you're not using html5mode which you did not mention so i'm assuming that's the case. If you use a regular link or $window.location.href then you basically skip ui-router magic and the browser should make a regular HTTP GET for /users which will reload the page and load everything from the start - in this case the other app.

Comment: @user2847643: `/users` goes to server and `users.ejs` handles it with `ng-app="MyAppAdminEnd"`. `/users` is being called from within `index.ejs` using the ng-app="MyAppFrontEnd". Basically, the `/users` route is handled using the `MyAppAdminEnd` app, but not in the `MyAppFrontEnd`.